# Replace last NA of a segment of NAs in a column with last valid value

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a sample data frame:

```
> df = data.frame(rep(seq(0, 120, length.out=6), times = 2), c(sample(1:50, 4), 
+ NA, NA, NA, sample(1:50, 5)))
> colnames(df) = c("Time", "Pat1")
> df
     Time Pat1
1     0   33
2    24   48
3    48    7
4    72    8
5    96   NA
6   120   NA
7     0   NA
8    24    1
9    48    6
10   72   28
11   96   31
12  120   32
```

NAs which have to be replaced are identified by `which` and logical operators:

```
x = which(is.na(df$Pat1) & df$Time == 0)
```

I know the `locf()` command, but it's replacing all NAs. How can I replace only the NAs at position x in a multi-column df?

---

EDIT: Here is a link to my original dataset: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9qdkorjnozvwmh/pad_88.csv)

And thats how far I get:

```
require(reshape2)
require(zoo)

pad.88 <- read.csv2("pad_88.csv")
colnames(pad.88) = c("Time", "Increment", "Side", 4:length(pad.88)-3)
attach(pad.88)

x = which(Time == 240 & Increment != 5)

pad.88 = pad.88[c(1:x[1], x[1]:x[2], x[2]:x[3], x[3]:x[4], x[4]:x[5], x[5]:x[6],x[6]:x[7], x[7]:x[8], x[8]:nrow(pad.88)),] 

y = which(duplicated(pad.88))
pad.88$Time[y] = 0

pad.88$Increment[y] = Increment[x] + 1

z = which(is.na(pad.88[4:ncol(pad.88)] & pad.88$Time == 0), arr.ind=T)
a = na.locf(pad.88[4:ncol(pad.88)])
```

My next step is something like `pat.cols[z] = a[z]`, which doesn't work.

---

That's how the result should look like:

```
Time Increment Side      1       2       3       4       5    ...

150     4       0   27,478  24,076  27,862  20,001  25,261
165     4       0   27,053  24,838  27,231  20,001  NA
180     4       0   27,599  24,166  27,862  20,687  NA
195     4       0   27,114  23,403  27,862  20,001  NA
210     4       0   26,993  24,076  27,189  19,716  NA
225     4       0   26,629  24,21   26,221  19,887  NA
240     4       0   26,811  26,228  26,431  20,001  NA
  0     5       1   26,811  26,228  26,431  20,001  25,261
 15     5       1   ....
```

The last valid value in col 5 is 25,261. This value replaces the NA at Time 0/Col 5.

Comment: Your question title is inconsistent with your description of `x` . Do you want specific `NA` values or the last `NA` in a given column?

Comment: Please provide a small subset of your linked data and, most important, what your desired result should look like.

Comment: The question title was valid for the simplified example, but the problem seems to be more complicated since in some columns there are more than one segments with NAs. The definition of x is right. I'm updating the question title.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it so that `x` records all the `NA` values and use the first and last from that to identify the locations you want.

```
df
   Time Pat1
1     0   36
2    24   13
3    48   32
4    72   38
5    96   NA
6   120   NA
7     0   NA
8    24    5
9    48   10
10   72    7
11   96   25
12  120   28

x <- which(is.na(df$Pat1))
df[rev(x)[1],"Pat1"] <- df[x[1]-1,"Pat1"]
df
   Time Pat1
1     0   36
2    24   13
3    48   32
4    72   38
5    96   NA
6   120   NA
7     0   38
8    24    5
9    48   10
10   72    7
11   96   25
12  120   28
```

For the multi-column example use the same idea in a `sapply` call:

```
cbind(df[1],sapply(df[-1],function(x) {y<-which(is.na(x));x[rev(y)[1]]<-x[y[1]-1];x}))
   Time Pat1 Pat2
1     0   41   42
2    24    8   30
3    48    3   41
4    72   14   NA
5    96   NA   NA
6   120   NA   NA
7     0   14   41
8    24    5   37
9    48   29   48
10   72   31   11
11   96   50   43
12  120   46   21
```

Comment: Seems like my sample was a bit too easy. How would you do it with the following df? `df = data.frame(rep(seq(0, 120, length.out=6), times = 2), c(sample(1:50, 4), NA, NA, NA, sample(1:50, 5)), 
c(sample(1:50, 3), NA, NA, NA, NA, sample(1:50, 5)))
        > colnames(df) = c("Time", "Pat1", "Pat2")` My real df has at least 18 columns.

Comment: @Markus That would be a more complicated problem. I'll have to think about it some more. `rle` would most likely be involved.